# Regex extracting paragraph including tab and new line delimeters

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string which contains text of the format:

```
 $textOne\n;
 \t$textTwo\n;
```

Example:

```
$textOne = Lorem Ipsum
$textTwo = is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make 

Output is in the picture.
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfoJA.png

This is all one string. I want to break up each section (Title and tabbed paragraph) into it's own element and have these all in an array. I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what regex pattern to use to find this element. If I broke on new line characters, that would give the title and paragraph separately which is not desired.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, please consider reading [Ask].

Comment: Does your variable contain all three of the repeated sections shown in your screenshot, or only one of them? (I assume all three, since you're asking how to split them up, but just want to make sure, since your example code only shows a single title and tabbed paragraph.) How do you set the value of the variable in the first place?

Comment: As per your figure each paragraph has same text and title. Also please provide more detail in your question. Give what you have tried so far (code) and also give some text here in question instead in picture.

Comment: I don't see how the text marked *Example* is "of the format" shown in the first block

Answer (score -2):

To answer my own question, I used:

```
'\n(?!\t)'
```